# i transfered over 300$ using EOSNCONTRACT wallet to another wallet but the token failed to deliver

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosjs, eosio-code, eosio.token

I transferred the eos token from one wallet to another using the **eosncontract wallet address**
Transaction id: 4458b2639b7cc5ffdde7785ed31d39a4910322baf2c220f0c0bc7d063e11e551
and 069897B0059684BC09E748B00F05617A280529A38BCC7FACAFFE2D59646AC89B

I can see the money sitting in the **eosncontract blockchain wallet**
its obvious there was a network glitch  because I have sent three different transactions using the same address and they are all successful apart from these two

someone please help me
[image]